# Field mContext is null in my AndroidTestCase but only when I run it with JUnit4

Tags: android, junit4, android-testing

Is this an issue or did I forget to implement something particular?

When I don't run it with JUnit 4 it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AndroidTestCase` is designed for use with JUnit3. You do not need it for JUnit4. Just call `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()` to get the `Context` of the app being tested, as shown below in a test case from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Testing/JUnit4):

```
/***
    Copyright (c) 2008-2015 CommonsWare, LLC
    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
    use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
    of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
    by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
    License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
    OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
    language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

    From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
        http://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.abf.test;

import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.test.AndroidTestCase;
import android.test.UiThreadTest;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import com.commonsware.android.abf.R;
import junit.framework.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class DemoContextTest {
  private View field=null;
  private View root=null;

  @Before
  public void init() {
    InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater
            .from(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext());

        root=inflater.inflate(R.layout.add, null);
      }
    });

    root.measure(800, 480);
    root.layout(0, 0, 800, 480);

    field=root.findViewById(R.id.title);
  }

  @Test
  public void exists() {
    Assert.assertNotNull(field);
  }

  @Test
  public void position() {
    Assert.assertEquals(0, field.getTop());
    Assert.assertEquals(0, field.getLeft());
  }
}
```